# How to include java.desktop module as a library jar in Proguard

Tags: java, swing, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

I use proguard to obfuscate an application in Java 11 (latest LTS version) using the proguard gradle plugin. This is the dependency currently. I would like to comment that I have to use a version >= 7.1.0-beta3 for other reasons that have to do with the project. However this issue is not related to that.

```
 com.guardsquare:proguard-gradle:7.1.0-beta4
```

Recently a dependency on `interface` [javax.swing.tree.TreeNode module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) was added.
The [javax.swing.tree.TreeNode module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreeNode.html) is part of the [java.desktop module](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/module-summary.html).

I use the following code to include the JDK libraries in java version independent way.
Following the [proguard examples](https://github.com/Guardsquare/proguard/blob/master/examples/gradle/applications.gradle).

```
        if (System.getProperty('java.version').startsWith('1.')) {
            libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
        } else {
            libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.base.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'
 }
```

However I get the following warning:

```
Warning: a.custom.CustomClass: can't find referenced class javax.swing.tree.TreeNode
Execution failed for task ':obfuscation_task'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

What does proguard need to 'see' the `javax.swing.tree.TreeNode` `class` as a libraryclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution as I was trying to add details to the question.

The reason for the error is that starting from Java 9 you have to explicitly specify which modules are added. The code in the question just adds the `java.base` module. To add the `java.desktop` module the following line should be added:

```
    libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.desktop.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'
```

The full part of java library inclusion is now:

```
    if (System.getProperty('java.version').startsWith('1.')) {
     
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/lib/rt.jar"
    } else {
     
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.base.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'
        libraryjars "${System.getProperty('java.home')}/jmods/java.desktop.jmod", jarfilter: '!**.jar', filter: '!module-info.class'
     
    }
```